# How can I implement OS2IP and I2OSP in C# cryptography?

Tags: c#, cryptography

What are the steps to implementing OS2IP and I2OSP? I'm reading [this](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-7.1) to find the steps, but to me they are very unclear. I'm trying to do both in C#.

OS2IP
Steps:

```
  1.  Let X_1 X_2 ... X_xLen be the octets of X from first to last,
      and let x_(xLen-i) be the integer value of the octet X_i for 1
      <= i <= xLen.

  2.  Let x = x_(xLen-1) 256^(xLen-1) + x_(xLen-2) 256^(xLen-2) +
      ...  + x_1 256 + x_0.

  3.  Output x.
```

I2OSP
Steps:

```
  1.  If x >= 256^xLen, output "integer too large" and stop.

  2.  Write the integer x in its unique xLen-digit representation in
      base 256:

         x = x_(xLen-1) 256^(xLen-1) + x_(xLen-2) 256^(xLen-2) + ...
         + x_1 256 + x_0,

      where 0 <= x_i < 256 (note that one or more leading digits
      will be zero if x is less than 256^(xLen-1)).
```

I'm more specifically confused on what it means when it says "x_i" or "x_1". I also just generally don't understand what the ^ operator is going to mean in this context, XOR or POW?

Comment: The `^` character means power in this case. Note that the [`BigInteger` constructor that takes a byte array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-numerics-biginteger-ctor(system-byte())) can *almost* be used to directly create a big integer according to OS2IP. You need to make one change, you must reverse the byte order in the array. OS2IP assumes a big-endian representation where as the constructor expects the array in little-endian order.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me and I didn't even need to make anything too complicated!